# How to center multiple images inside anchor tag

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want the images in center but unable to do this on `medium`, `large` and `extra-large` screens

```
 <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="/html"><img src="./images/devices.png" alt="devices"></a>
            <a href="/html"><img src="./images/media.png" alt="media"></a>
            <a href="/html"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <a href="/html"><img src="./images/stream.png" alt="stream"></a>
            <a href="/html"><img src="./images/logout.png" alt="logout"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried different solutions provided on `stackoverflow` site but none worked. Please help, I am a newbie

Comment: What are the image sizes? Can you reference the actual images? Why are you using a `.row` inside the `navbar`? You should only use the [supported Navbar content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content).

Answer (score -2):

I don't really understand what you need, but I guess you can refer to the following 2 pages:

- [.nav class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/)
- [.navbar class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)

Usually navigations are either a bar with multiple links or dropdowns. So I don't see how this can be justified.

Here-under 2 examples one with the .nav class that I've arranged horizontally.
One with the .navbar class I've arranged vertically.

The content of the items is centered.

Hope this helps.

```css
.navbar, .nav {
background-color: #A4A4A4;
border: 1px solid red;
}

/* for the purpose of demonstration, I added borders to the Nav-ul */
#top-menu {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-link {
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
/* for the purpose of demonstration, I added borders to the list items */
border: 1px solid black;
}

.dont_copy_this {height: 50px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/devices.png" alt="devices"></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/media.png" alt="media"></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/stream.png" alt="stream"></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/logout.png" alt="logout"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="dont_copy_this"></div>

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul id="top-menu" class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/devices.png" alt="devices"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/media.png" alt="media"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/stream.png" alt="stream"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/html"><img src="./images/logout.png" alt="logout"></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```